# How to fix timeless execution in cypher query - Neo4j Graph Database?

Tags: json, database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm dealing with the import of **Common Weakness Enumeration Catalog** (.json file) to the Neo4j Graph Database, using cypher language query and the apoc library. Although **i import properly the fields: Weaknesses, Views, External_References**, i have an execution problem (without any error) with the import of the field: **Categories** which is executing without ending. Below i present the structure of .json file and my cypher code.

```
"Weakness_Catalog": {
   "Weaknesses": {"Weakness":[...]}
   "Categories": {"Category":[...]}
   "Views": {"View":[...]}
   "External_References": {"External_Reference":[...]}
}
```

*Cypher Query*

After several tests i think that the logic error is between the last 2 parts [*with value....(catRef)*], without them, the query executes pretty good, at normal time. I've also changed a setting param. at the db configuration file due to an error (**cypher.lenient_create_relationship = true**). And i tested the different import sequence with the same bad results (weakness, categories, views, ext. references etc.)

```
call apoc.load.json(files) yield value
                                unwind value.Weakness_Catalog.Weaknesses.Weakness as weakness
                                merge (i:GeneralInfo_CWE {Name:value.Weakness_Catalog.Name, Version:value.Weakness_Catalog.Version,
                                                        Date:value.Weakness_Catalog.Date, Schema:'https://cwe.mitre.org/data/xsd/cwe_schema_v6.4.xsd'})
                                
                                merge(w:CWE {Name:'CWE-' + weakness.ID})
                                set w.Extended_Name=weakness.Name, w.Abstraction=weakness.Abstraction,
                                w.Structure=weakness.Structure, w.Status=weakness.Status, w.Description=weakness.Description,
                                w.Extended_Description= apoc.convert.toString(weakness.Extended_Description),
                                w.Likelihood_Of_Exploit=weakness.Likelihood_Of_Exploit,
                                w.Background_Details=apoc.convert.toString(weakness.Background_Details.Background_Detail),
                                w.Modes_Of_Introduction=[value in weakness.Modes_Of_Introduction.Introduction | value.Phase],
                                w.Submission_Date=weakness.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Date,
                                w.Submission_Name=weakness.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Name,
                                w.Submission_Organization=weakness.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Organization,
                                w.Modifications=[value in weakness.Content_History.Modification | apoc.convert.toString(value)],
                                w.Alternate_Terms=apoc.convert.toString(weakness.Alternate_Terms),
                                w.Notes=[value in weakness.Notes.Note | apoc.convert.toString(value)],
                                w.Affected_Resources=[value in weakness.Affected_Resources.Affected_Resource | value],
                                w.Functional_Areas=[value in weakness.Functional_Areas.Functional_Area | value]
                                
                                merge (w)-[:belongsTo]->(i)
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                unwind weakness.Related_Weaknesses.Related_Weakness as Rel_Weakness
                                match (cwe:CWE) where cwe.Name='CWE-' + Rel_Weakness.CWE_ID
                                merge (w)-[:Related_Weakness{Nature:Rel_Weakness.Nature}]->(cwe)
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                unwind weakness.Applicable_Platforms as appPl
                                    foreach (lg in appPl.Language |
                                        merge(ap:Applicable_Platform{Type:'Language', Prevalence:lg.Prevalence,
                                                Name:coalesce(lg.Name, 'NOT SET'), Class:coalesce(lg.Class, 'NOT SET')})
                                        merge(w)-[:Applicable_Platform]->(ap))
                                
                                    with w, weakness, value, appPl
                                    foreach (tch in appPl.Technology |
                                        merge(ap:Applicable_Platform{Type:'Technology', Prevalence:tch.Prevalence,
                                                Name:coalesce(tch.Name, 'NOT SET'), Class:coalesce(tch.Class, 'NOT SET')})
                                        merge(w)-[:Applicable_Platform]->(ap))
                                   
                                    with w, weakness, value, appPl
                                    foreach (arc in appPl.Architecture |
                                        merge(ap:Applicable_Platform{Type:'Architecture', Prevalence:arc.Prevalence,
                                                Name:coalesce(arc.Name, 'NOT SET'), Class:coalesce(arc.Class, 'NOT SET')})
                                        merge(w)-[:Applicable_Platform]->(ap))
                                    
                                    with w, weakness, value, appPl
                                    foreach (os in appPl.Operating_System |
                                        merge(ap:Applicable_Platform{Type:'Operating System', Prevalence:os.Prevalence,
                                                Name:coalesce(os.Name, 'NOT SET'), Class:coalesce(os.Class, 'NOT SET')})
                                        merge(w)-[:Applicable_Platform]->(ap))             
                           
                           
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (example in weakness.Demonstrative_Examples.Demonstrative_Example |
                                    merge(ex:Demonstrative_Example {Intro_Text:apoc.convert.toString(example.Intro_Text)})
                                    set ex.Body_Text=[value in example.Body_Text | apoc.convert.toString(value)],
                                    ex.Example_Code=[value in example.Example_Code | apoc.convert.toString(value)]                                
                                    merge (w)-[:hasExample]->(ex))
                                                                
                                                     
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (consequence in weakness.Common_Consequences.Consequence |
                                    merge (con:Consequence{CWE:w.Name, Scope:[value in consequence.Scope | value]})
                                    set con.Impact=[value in consequence.Impact | value],
                                    con.Note=consequence.Note, con.Likelihood=consequence.Likelihood
                                    merge(w)-[:hasConsequence]->(con))
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (dec in weakness.Detection_Methods.Detection_Method |
                                    merge(d:Detection_Method {Method:dec.Method})
                                    merge(w)-[wd:canBeDetected{Description:apoc.convert.toString(dec.Description)}]->(d)
                                    set wd.Effectiveness=dec.Effectiveness, wd.Effectiveness_Notes=dec.Effectiveness_Notes,
                                    wd.Detection_Method_ID=dec.Detection_Method_ID)                                
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (mit in weakness.Potential_Mitigations.Mitigation |
                                    merge(m:Mitigation {Description:apoc.convert.toString(mit.Description)})
                                    set m.Phase=[value in mit.Phase | value], m.Strategy=mit.Strategy,
                                    m.Effectiveness=mit.Effectiveness, m.Effectiveness_Notes=mit.Effectiveness_Notes,
                                    m.Mitigation_ID=mit.Mitigation_ID
                                    merge(w)-[:hasMitigation]->(m))
                                    
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (rap in weakness.Related_Attack_Patterns.Related_Attack_Pattern |
                                    merge(cp:CAPEC {Name:rap.CAPEC_ID})
                                    merge(w)-[:RelatedAttackPattern]->(cp))
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                foreach (reference in value.Weakness_Catalog.External_References.External_Reference |
                                    merge(r:External_Reference{Reference_ID:reference.Reference_ID})
                                    set r.Author=[value in reference.Author | value], r.Title=reference.Title,
                                        r.Edition=reference.Edition, r.URL=reference.URL,
                                        r.Publication_Year=reference.Publication_Year, r.Publisher=reference.Publisher)
                                
                                with w, weakness, value
                                unwind weakness.References.Reference as exReference
                                match (ref:External_Reference) where ref.Reference_ID=exReference.External_Reference_ID
                                merge(w)-[:hasExternal_Reference]->(ref)
                                                 
                                                                
                                with value
                                unwind value.Weakness_Catalog.Views.View as view
                                merge (v:CWE_VIEW{ViewID:view.ID})
                                set v.Name=view.Name, v.Type=view.Type, v.Status=view.Status,
                                v.Objective=apoc.convert.toString(view.Objective), v.Filter=view.Filter,
                                v.Notes=apoc.convert.toString(view.Notes),
                                v.Submission_Name=view.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Name,
                                v.Submission_Date=view.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Date,
                                v.Submission_Organization=view.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Organization,
                                v.Modification=[value in view.Content_History.Modification | apoc.convert.toString(value)]
                                
                                foreach (value in view.Audience.Stakeholder |
                                    merge (st:Stakeholder{Type:value.Type})
                                    merge (v)-[rel:usefulFor]->(st)
                                    set rel.Description=value.Description)
                                
                                with v, view, value
                                unwind (case view.Members.Has_Member when [] then [null] else view.Members.Has_Member end) as members
                                optional match (MemberWeak:CWE{Name:'CWE-' + members.CWE_ID})
                                merge (v)-[:hasMember{ViewID:members.View_ID}]->(MemberWeak)                                
                                
                                                                                                                                
                                with v, view, value
                                unwind (case view.References.Reference when [] then [null] else view.References.Reference end) as viewExReference
                                optional match (viewRef:External_Reference{Reference_ID:viewExReference.External_Reference_ID})
                                merge (v)-[:hasExternal_Reference{ViewID:v.ViewID}]->(viewRef)
                                
                                with value
                                unwind value.Weakness_Catalog.Categories.Category as category
                                merge (c:CWE_Category{CategoryID:category.ID})
                                set c.Name=category.Name, c.Status=category.Status, c.Summary=apoc.convert.toString(category.Summary),
                                c.Notes=apoc.convert.toString(category.Notes), c.Submission_Name=category.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Name,
                                c.Submission_Date=category.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Date,
                                c.Submission_Organization=category.Content_History.Submission.Submission_Organization,
                                c.Modification=[value in category.Content_History.Modification | apoc.convert.toString(value)]
                                
                                with c, category
                                unwind (case category.References.Reference when [] then [null] else category.References.Reference end) as categoryExReference
                                optional match (catRef:External_Reference{Reference_ID:categoryExReference.External_Reference_ID})
                                merge (c)-[:hasExternal_Reference{CategoryID:c.CategoryID}]->(catRef)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that every time i use with, i'm working in nested loops. The more nested loops, the slower the query will be. A good way to speed up, is to create simplier queries when it's possible.

For example in the json file:

```
"Weakness_Catalog": {
   "Weaknesses": {"Weakness":[...]}
   "Categories": {"Category":[...]}
   "Views": {"View":[...]}
   "External_References": {"External_Reference":[...]}
}
```

i will execute one query for Weaknesses, one for Categories, one for Views and one for External_References.